# Clear Table when Session Ends Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

In my current shopping cart setup, I give the user the ability to add items to his cart within his session.  The cart takes the session ID and the product info and creates a new `@cart.lineitems` record.  However, when the user's session ends, their cart is not deleted from the database.  This produces hiccups in my code and leaves a messy slate.  My question is *how do I delete the current Cart row when an user's session ends?*

Code:

**Models**

```
class Views::CartsController < ApplicationController
    layout 'views'
    def show
    @cart = current_cart
  end
end

    class Views::Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
      # attr_accessible :title, :body
      has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
      has_one :order, :dependent => :destroy

      def total_price
        # convert to array so it doesn't try to do sum on database directly
        line_items.to_a.sum(&:full_price)
      end
    end
    class Views::LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :cart, :quantity, :image, :unit_price, :product_id, :album_id
      belongs_to :cart
      belongs_to :image
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :image

      def full_price
        unit_price * quantity
      end
    end
```

**Controller**

```
class Views::LineItemsController < ApplicationController
    layout 'views'
    def create
    @product = Image.find(params[:product_id])
    @album = @product.album
    attr = {:cart => current_cart, :album_id => @album.id, :product_id => @product.id, :quantity => 1, :unit_price => 10}
    @current = Views::LineItem.find_by_product_id(@product.id)
    if @current.nil?
        Views::LineItem.create(attr)
    else
        @current.update_attributes(:quantity => @current.quantity + 1, :cart => current_cart)
    end
    # @line_item = @current ? Views::LineItem.create(:cart => current_cart, :album_id => @album.id, :product_id => @product.id, :quantity => 1, :unit_price => 10) : @current.update_attribute(:quantity, @current.quantity + 1)
    flash[:notice] = "Added #{@product.title} to cart."
    redirect_to current_cart_url
  end
  def destroy
    @line_item = Views::LineItem.find(params[:id])
    if @line_item.quantity > 1
        @line_item.update_attribute(:quantity, @line_item.quantity - 1)
    else
        @line_item.destroy
    end
    redirect_to current_cart_url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be incorrect but going by what you've said you may want to have something like this in a `CartsController`

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

      def destroy
        @cart = current_cart #Get current cart
        @cart.destroy #call destroy method on the current cart
        session[:cart_id] = nil #Ensuring that user is deleting their own cart
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to(root_url,
                                    :flash => {:error => 'Your cart is currently empty'}) }
        end
      end
    end
```

Alternatively could try and work with following in the `application_controller`

```
  def current_cart  
    if user_signed_in?
      if session[:cart_id]  
        @current_cart ||= current_user.carts.find(session[:cart_id])
        if @current_cart.purchased_at || @current_cart.expired?
          session[:cart_id] = nil
        end
      end  
      if session[:cart_id].nil?  
        @current_cart = current_user.carts.create!  
        session[:cart_id] ||= @current_cart.id  
      end
    end
    @current_cart  
  end
```

Comment: Only thing is how do I set the cart to "expire" if the user never deletes it?

Comment: @derek_duncan see my alternative method that may work for you

Answer (score 0):

You could store the user_id and the session_id in your cart row and then scope it to only see the items relevant to their current session. If you wanted to clean up the table regularly, set up a cron job.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

https://github.com/javan/whenever